# Checking covariate balance in survey response

Tags: r, survey, covariate-balance

In survey adjustment for nonresponse, a model-based approach can model response propensity on a variable where each observation is a respondent or nonrespondent from the full sample.

An approach to adjustment for nonresponse taken is to fit a response propensity model (logit) with responded to survey as the outcome (Resp) and covariates as characteristics (i.e., age, race, sex). Then check for balance by creating 5 classes of response propensity based on quintiles and saving as a factor (p.class) and fitting a model for each covariate in the propensity model, with the factor variable p.class and resp as predictors and an interaction of these two. For example:

```
data(nhis)

# Create a varaible with 5 values and treat as a factor
p.class <-pclass(formula = resp ~ age + 
                   as.factor(hisp) + 
                   as.factor(race) + 
                   as.factor(parents_r) + 
                   as.factor(educ_r), 
                 type = "unwtd", data = nhis, link = "logit", numcl = 5)

table(p.class$p.class, useNA= "always")

# Fit an unweighted model for each covariate in the propensity model, with the factor variable p.class and resp as predictors
p.class <- p.class$p.class
glm.age <- glm(age ~ p.class + 
                 resp + 
                 resp*p.class, 
               data = nhis)
summary(glm.age)
```

What are some similarities and differences between checking for covariate balance between this approach and causal inference - where you check for balance between treated and untreated groups?